# Unable to install Ubuntu 15.04 (Vivid Vervet) due to partition failure

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation

I am attempting to install Ubuntu on a refurbished Lenovo Thinkpad T420 with a 128 gig SSD. There is a 70 gig win7 partition and the rest of the space is unallocated, as I shrunk the win7 partition in Windows. I'm booting Ubuntu from a flash-drive. Both when using the Ubuntu installer and when using GParted, I am unable to create partitions.

**GParted error log when attempting a swap partition:**

```
GParted 0.19.0 --enable-libparted-dmraid --enable-online-resize

Libparted 3.2
Create Primary Partition #1 (linux-swap, 1.95 GiB) on /dev/sda  00:00:00    ( ERROR )

create empty partition  00:00:00    ( SUCCESS )

path: /dev/sda3
start: 168146944
end: 172242943
size: 4096000 (1.95 GiB)
clear old file system signatures in /dev/sda3  00:00:00    ( SUCCESS )

write 68.00 KiB of zeros at byte offset 0  00:00:00    ( SUCCESS )
write 4.00 KiB of zeros at byte offset 67108864  00:00:00    ( SUCCESS )
write 4.00 KiB of zeros at byte offset 2097147904  00:00:00    ( SUCCESS )
flush operating system cache of /dev/sda  00:00:00    ( SUCCESS )
set partition type on /dev/sda3  00:00:00    ( SUCCESS )

new partition type: linux-swap(v1)
create new linux-swap file system  00:00:00    ( ERROR )

mkswap -L "" /dev/sda3

/dev/sda3: No such file or directory
```

========================================

**GParted error log when attempting an ext4 partition:**

```
Create Primary Partition #1 (ext4, 39.06 GiB) on /dev/sda  00:00:00    ( ERROR )

create empty partition  00:00:00    ( SUCCESS )

path: /dev/sda3
start: 168146944
end: 250068991
size: 81922048 (39.06 GiB)
clear old file system signatures in /dev/sda3  00:00:00    ( SUCCESS )

write 68.00 KiB of zeros at byte offset 0  00:00:00    ( SUCCESS )
write 4.00 KiB of zeros at byte offset 67108864  00:00:00    ( SUCCESS )
write 4.00 KiB of zeros at byte offset 41944084480  00:00:00    ( SUCCESS )
flush operating system cache of /dev/sda  00:00:00    ( SUCCESS )
set partition type on /dev/sda3  00:00:00    ( SUCCESS )

new partition type: ext4
create new ext4 file system  00:00:00    ( ERROR )

mkfs.ext4 -L "" /dev/sda3

mke2fs 1.42.12 (29-Aug-2014)
The file /dev/sda3 does not exist and no size was specified
```

.

=============================================================================

Please tell me I am just doing something really stupid. I am new to this!
Don't really understand what's happening. When using the installer it displays the error message: `The creation of swap space in partition #3 of SCSI5 (0,0,0)(sda) failed.` And when I tried to install Ubuntu without a swap partition, it displayed a similar message about being unable to create an ext4 partition.

==============================================================================
Screenshots:

Gparted before allocation: 
[image]

with linux swap partition allocated: 
[image]

Comment: Please start gparted from your flash driver and give a link to a screenshot.

Comment: And what is the problem? You created a swap partition, now create another ext4 partition and press "Apply".

Comment: But this is what happens when I press apply: http://i.imgur.com/FxH4PWy.png

It fails to create the partition...

Comment: And then afterwards it looks like this: http://i.imgur.com/oNAxjnO.png
What was supposed to be a swap partition becomes an unknown partition